# Does heapify(int rootIndex) only builds heap for the heap rooted at the input rootIndex?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, heap, binary-heap, max-heap

So the heapify operation is something like this (say we are discussing binary max heaps).

```
maxHeapify(int rootIndex){
    int largestIndex = rootIndex;
    int largest = heap[rootIndex];
    if (largest < heap[leftChildIndexOf(rootIndex)]){
        largestIndex = leftChildIndexOf(rootIndex);
    }
    if (largest < heap[rightChildIndexOf(rootIndex)]){
        largestIndex = rightChildIndexOf(rootIndex);
    }
    if (largestIndex != rootIndex){
        //Swap heap[rootIndex] & heap[largestIndex]
        maxHeapify(largestIndex);
    }

}
```

This heapify operation has an assumption that the max heap properties are being satisfied everywhere except possibly at the input rootIndex.
Now, consider a scenario like this,

```
          6
         / \
        5   4
      /   \
    7      6
   / \    / \
  6   6  6   6
```

Clearly, the max heap property is being violated where 5 is present.
If we run `maxHeapify` on the heap rooted at 5, the resulting heap becomes,

```
          6
         / \
        7   4
      /   \
    5      6
   / \    / \
  6   6  6   6
```

And then the `maxHeapify` function recursively moves down to the heap rooted at 5 now, and it finally becomes,

```
          6
         / \
        7   4
      /   \
    6      6
   / \    / \
  5   6  6   6
```

However, the max heap property is also being violated at 7, but since `maxHeapify` recursively moves down, it doesn't touch that.

Is it valid to assume that `maxHeapify(int rootIndex)` will only ensure that at the end of all recursive calls, the heap rooted at `rootIndex` will satisfy max heap property, but nothing can be said about the heap rooted at `parentIndexOf(rootIndex)`?

Comment: Looks like you already answered your own question, and it's a yes.

Answer (score 0):

That heapify operation does even less than that.  It cannot fix arbitrary errors in the heap rooted at `rootIndex`.

The only problem it can fix is a root that is too small -- the two subtrees of the root must already satisfy the heap property in order for it to work correctly.